Show that the area between the four infinite branches of the curve $x^2y^2 = a^2(x^2+y^2)$ and its asymptotes is equal to 4$a^2$.
$x^2y^2 = a^2(x^2 + y^2)$
This question is from my engineering maths Book. So, it is know the curve is symmetric about X and Y axes, since on replacing $x$ to $-x$ and $y$ to $-y$, the curve remains the same. Asymptotes are $y=±a$ and $x=±a$, obtained by equating the highest degree terms of x and y in the equation of curve to zero. Also, the function is not defined between $-a$ and $a$. After tracing the curve, I shifted the origin to ($a,a$) by making the substitution $x = X + a$ and $y = Y + a$. After evaluation for one branch, the result can be multiplied by 4 due to symmetric nature of function.
However, when I tried to integrate the new function, it is tending to infinity.
The new function -
$Y = a[(X+a)/\sqrt{(X+a)^2-a^2}-1)$
$\int YdX$ = $\int_0^{\infty}a[(X+a)/\sqrt{(X+a)^2-a^2}-1) dX$
Take ${(X+a)^2 - a^2}$ = $t$
$2(X+a)dX = dt$
Now this integral is evaluating to a $\infty$ - $\infty$ form.
I would like some help on this question. Thanks.

Please explicitly show your steps for "when I tried to integrate the new function, ..."

@CalvinLin i did just now.  please let me know if i missed something.

Note that the given equation is invariant under $x\leftrightarrow y$ too. So you can actually divide the region of interest into eight parts of equal area. One of those eight parts is the region bounded by the given curve (black), $y=a$ (red), and $x=y$ (blue), shown in the figure below. [I made the sketch for $a=1$, which is why the asymptotes are at $x=1$ and $y=1$ (both red).]
It turns out to be simpler to use polar coordinates. Then, the given equation (black curve) becomes
$$
r^2 = \frac{a^2}{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}.
$$
The line $y=a$ (horizontal red line) is given by $r\sin\theta=a$. The shaded region is the region between these two curves for $0\le \theta\le \pi/4$. Therefore, the area of the shaded region is
$$
\frac12\int_0^{\pi/4} [r_\text{curve}^2(\theta) - r_{y=a}^2(\theta)] d\theta = \frac{a^2}2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \sec^2\theta d\theta = \frac{a^2}2 \int_0^1 du = \frac{a^2}2.
$$
where I substituted $u=\tan\theta$. Multiplying by $8$ gives the desired answer of $4a^2$.


thanks a lot. this is perfect.

You’re welcome! Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it’s helpful.

Hi @Pranay, can you allow part of your graph be C&P ed? Thanks.

@Narasimham. Sure, please go ahead!

As you noted the curve and its asymptotes is symmetric about the $x$ and $y$ axes, then just calculate the bounded area in the positive $xy$ plane and take $4$ times of it.
The curve in the $+xy$ plane is given through:
$$x^2y^2 - a^2y^2 = a^2x^2 \iff y = \frac{+ax}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}$$

There is no need to translate the curve by $-a$ along the $x$ axis. The area is bounded by the asymptotes $x = a,\,y = a$ and $y = \frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}$. So, your bound for $x$ is $x \in (a, \infty)$, and to bound above $y = a$, we simply remove the rectangular area under $y = a$ which is as show below:


$$\to A= \int_{x=a}^{\infty}{\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}}dx - \int_{x=a}^{\infty}{(y=a)dx}
\\= a\int_{a}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}} - 1 \right)dx}
\\= a\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\left( \sqrt{x^2 - a^2} - x \right)} - a\left( \sqrt{a^2 - a^2} - a \right)
\\= a\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\left( \sqrt{x^2 - a^2} - \sqrt{x^2} \right)} + a^2
\\= a\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\left( \frac{x^2 - a^2 - x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2} + \sqrt{x^2}} \right)} + a^2
\\ = 0 + a^2$$

$$\therefore 4A = 4a^2$$


We have the curve equation in cartesian and polar coordinates
$$x^2y^2 = a^2(x^2 + y^2); ~ r^2 = \frac{a^2}{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta};$$
The graph exhibits symmetry about $(x,y)$ axes and anti-symmetry about the origin.
We evaluate the integral between $\theta$ limits $(0, \pi/4)$ which can be later multiplied by 8 for the full area. The quarter area
$$A=\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac12 \cdot\frac{4a^2d\theta}{4 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta  } =\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{a^2d 2\theta}{4 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta  } $$
Let $2\theta=u$ so we have
$$A=a^2~\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{du}{\sin^2 u}=|-\cot u |^{\pi/2}_{0}\to - (\cot \pi/2- \cot 0) = \cot 0 $$
This does not converge, goes to $\infty;$
